# sqldf can't find the data with error "no such table"

Tags: r, sqldf

I've been using sqldf in my R-scripts until now when I got the following error:

```
library(sqldf)
data(mtcars)
out <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM mtcars")

> Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: mtcars
```

This hasn't been a problem before now, anyone know what's the issue?

Comment: `no such table: mtcars` did you connect correct schema

Comment: > mtcars[1,]
          mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4

The data frame works as expected

Comment: It's working fine for me on macOS. Might therefore be a platform dependant issue

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqldf (and in general look at the BugReports line of the Description file).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem with 0.4-10 from CRAN (Windows 10).

```
> out <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM mtcars")
Loading required package: tcltk
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: mtcars
```

Then I upgraded from GitHub, version 0.4-11

```
> devtools::install_github("ggrothendieck/sqldf")
Downloading GitHub repo ggrothendieck/sqldf@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/ggrothendieck/sqldf/zipball/master
Installing sqldf
Installing 1 package: DBI
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/romunov/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/DBI_0.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 746913 bytes (729 KB)
downloaded 729 KB

package ‘DBI’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\romunov\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6vYjwO\downloaded_packages
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ  \
  --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/romunov/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6vYjwO/devtoolsdb05f0015fc/ggrothendieck-sqldf-af1277f"  \
  --library="C:/Users/romunov/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'sqldf' ...
** R
** demo
** inst
** tests
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (sqldf)
Reloading installed sqldf
> sqldf("SELECT * FROM mtcars LIMIT 6")
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Looking at the last two commits from GitHub, no substantial change has been done to `sqldf` package. `DBI` did get upgraded to 0.7, though, which might have solved the problem. Gabor might chip in with the details.

Comment: The problem is that RSQLite 2.0 was just released and does not work with older versions of sqldf. sqldf 0.4-11 which was just released should be used (or else use an older version of RSQLite).

Comment: Ah, so not DBI. I had assumed DBI was causing this because that's the only thing I see updating when installing a new version of sqldf.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck perhaps dependencies of the packages should be fixed somehow, so that users don't bump to this problem over and over again. June 2018 and I still encountered this problem.